# Getting Error While Defining Stored Procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to define stored procedure in mysql but getting error i am unable to understand what i am doing wrong.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE distance(lat1 Float,long1 Float,lat2 Float,long2 Float,OUT distance Float)
BEGIN

    SET distance =  ROUND((ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2))+COS(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1)))*6371), 2);

END
```

ERROR:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Delimiters to resolve this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE distance(lat1 Float,long1 Float,lat2 Float,long2 Float,OUT distance Float)
BEGIN

    SET distance =  ROUND((ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2))+COS(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1)))*6371), 2);

END //
delimiter ;
```